# Recovery and Norecovery in SQL Server Database Backup

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I am using SQL server 2012,I have sequence of backup file.Now i am restoring.
by mistake, Suppose i restore file with Recovery rather than Norecovery then how to restore further files?

Comment: restart the `restore` process and specify the correct `recovery`

Comment: means i have to restore all files from begining . Is there any way to use Norecovery without restoring any db.

Comment: Nope. You have to restart from begining

Comment: Ok thanks @Squirrel